# PHP json_decode skips part of source JSON

Tags: php, json, import

I have a problem with a piece of JSON and PHP's `json_decode()`. 
We receive JSON from a customer's publishing solution, and although it validates, `json_decode()` skips parts of it.

```
{
 "articles":{
  "article":{
     "title":"This is the title",
     "document":{
        "text_article":{
           "p":[
              "- The first sentence.",
              " "
           ],
           "h3":"The first subtitle",
           "p":[
              "- One sentence.",
              "Another sentence.",
              "- A quote.",
              " "
           ],
           "h3":{
              "strong":"Second subtitle"
           },
           "p":[
              "An additional sentence",
              "One more.",
              {
                 "a":{
                    "href":"https://www.example.com",
                    "target":"_blank",
                    "$":"Link text"
                 }
              },
              "(Some extra information near the bottom)"
           ]
        }
     },
     "knr":"0001"
  }
 }
}
```

After import it looks like this:

```
{
  "articles": {
    "article": {
        "title": "This is the title",
        "document": {
            "text_article": {
                "p": [
                    "An additional sentence",
                    "One more.",
                    {
                        "a": {
                            "href": "https://www.example.com",
                            "target": "_blank",
                            "$": "Link text"
                        }
                    },
                    "(Some extra information near the bottom)"
                ],
                "h3": {
                    "strong": "Second subtitle"
                }
            }
        },
        "knr": "0001"
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect the problem is the presence of several "p" and "h3" elements in "text_article". But [this online validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) displays it as intended, so our customer is under the impression that it is correct. ([JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) shows the same problem as `json_decode()` though)

Any way to get this to import correctly to PHP, or am I correct in pushing for a rewrite of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get that to work. json_decode exports the data as php objects or arrays - and therefore no duplicate keys / properties are allowed.

Maybe you can convince the customer to change the json format into something like this:

```
{
    "articles":{
        "article":{
            "title":"This is the title",
            "document":{
                "text_article":[
                    {
                        "type":"p",
                        "content":[
                            "- The first sentence."
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"h3",
                        "content":[
                            "The first subtitle."
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"p",
                        "content":[
                            "- One sentence.",
                            "Another sentence.",
                            "- A quote."
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "knr":"0001"
        }
    }
}
```

There, you have an array `text_article` containing objects for each tag - each containing an array of contents. The objects can be extended by further attributes as needed.

Comment: Is it a limitation in PHP, that might not be there in other programming languages? In that case the customer might be correct, and I need to look at an intermediate solution.

Comment: I do not know of any programming language not having that limitation. AND I am quite sure, that the used development language should not depend on the data format provided by the customer. At least, you could write some kind of parser, which changes the structure of the json file before using `json_decode`.

Comment: Looks like the best solution is as you suggested then, I'll try to get the customer to change their JSON to use an array.

Answer (score 1):

just to add a possible option...

the library [jsonlint](https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint) can be used to validate your json string.  It will take arguments to either ignore/detect duplicate keys.

whilst this wont fix your problem, at least youd be able to detect any errors so avoiding data corruption.